# Decode getting ORA-00938 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My current SQL is as below:

```
CASE
    WHEN PARENT.ASLNO IS NULL THEN SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST
    -- #5098
    ELSE DECODE(ASL.CATEGORY_NAME, null,
      NVL(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,
        SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST),
      decode(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,null,null,'N/A'))
    -- End #5098
END AS SUPSPD_SUBCATEGORY_LIST
```

I am trying to change the following sql

```
DECODE(ASL.CATEGORY_NAME, null,
  NVL(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,
    SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST),
  decode(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,null,null,'N/A'))
```

to

```
DECODE(ASL.CATEGORY_NAME, null,
  DECODE(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,
    SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST),
  decode(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,null,null,'N/A'))
```

but I am getting ORA-00938 not enough arguments for function?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am still working on this change.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
  NVL(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,
    SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST)
```

returns the parent subcategory list if the child's is null.

Decode needs [at least three arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm)m but you're only supplied two; you have the first `search` value but no result, and no `default` either, which means you don't always get a value back.

The equivalent for your NVL would be:

```
  DECODE(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST, NULL,
    SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST, SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIS),
```

I'm not really sure why you'd want to make the statement longer and a bit harder to understand... for some consistency I might even be tempted to change

```
  decode(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST,null,null,'N/A')
```

to

```
  NVL2(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST, 'N/A', null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have changed:

```
NVL(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST, SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST)
```

to:

```
DECODE(SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST, SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST)
```

DECODE needs at least 3 arguments.

**Aside**

I find it much easier to debug complex expressions like this by laying them out nicely just like any other code:

```
DECODE( ASL.CATEGORY_NAME
      , null
      , DECODE ( SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST
               , SUBCATEGORIES_PARENT.SUBCATEGORY_LIST
               )
      , decode ( SUBCATEGORIES.SUBCATEGORY_LIST
               , null
               , null
               , 'N/A'
               )
      )
```